# Code used in Ruby on rails official API document incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been reading the official ruby on rails API document and came across a strange notation that I couldn't find anywhere else. For example on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

it is full of codes that start with "<%Q", such as:

> <%Q form_for @post do |f| %>
>     ...

I first thought I'm missing something and this was another type of declaration, since this is an official document. All I know are "<% ... %>" and "<%= ... %>"s, but after googling this for a while now, I feel like this may be an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals and look for `%Q`. I think it might come from that. But I never uses it.

Comment: Thanks Robin, but why would they use it in an official document? It's almost like wanting people to have hard time understanding the document. Also, it's not just "<%Q"'s, but if you look in the document, there are codes like " <%= f.submit %Q< " I can't possibly imagine how to translate this. The next best interpretation was just to think %Q< was a typo for %>, but the document uses that notation all throughout, and inconsistently.

Comment: %Q is definitely valid Ruby syntax *by itself* (i.e. %Q{something}) but it's not valid in this context. See my answer for information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is wrong due to a bug in the RDoc parser that Rails uses. See here for more information: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-docs/browse_thread/thread/bc1ae76aa8179406.

Comment: Thank you so much. That thread seems to have been around for a couple of weeks. Hopefully someone fixes it soon. After all, it's THE official document for ruby on rails. As a first time learner that kind of small error really confuses the hell out of me :(

Answer (score 1):

I think something must be acting up with the rdoc/sdoc scripts that generate the api docs from the source code - there's no trace of %Q in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb) from which the api documentation is generated.